# Debugging in WebStorm vs Visual Studio

Tags: webstorm

For the longest time I have not been able to debug in WebStorm and I am wondering if I am going about it wrong. When using Visual Studio to debug a C# application I set my breakpoint and click the green triangle to start/debug my web application.

[image]

This is also the way I have been attempting to debug Angular applications in WebStorm. However, my breakpoints never seem to be hit. So today I tried (quite by accident) clicking the green triangle in WebStorm to start my Angular application as normal (launching via webpack) and then after it loaded I clicked the green "bug" icon. I then found that when navigating through my angular application my breakpoints were hit.

[image]

then

[image]

Was I doing this wrong the whole time? I was thinking that it was just one click as in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yep, that is it!

Comment: I follow this: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-angular-apps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found it! Yes, you have to click the bug icon to get breakpoints to work.

Comment: I know I must sound slow but I never realized that the application already had to be running in WebStorm in order to be able to launch debugging. I was so used to how Visual Studio did it. I don't recall the WebStorm documentation mentioning that either. I hate to think I am the only one confused by this but perhaps I am.